# Заменить NaN на -1 в столбце если в другом столбце значение равно 1

Tags: python, pandas

Есть набор данных, надо у объектов, где значение в столбце `1`, заменить в другом столбце той же строки `NaN`  на `-1`.

Пояснение:
Столбец `heduc` - длительность получения образования мужем (если мужа нет стоит `NaN`, надо заменить на `-1`)
Столбец `newermarr` - статус, состоит ли человек в браке (если `1` не состоит)
нужно чтобы у всех безбрачных, срок получения образования мужем = `-1`.

Вот попытка решения, но не могу понять как в `else` оставить уже имеющиеся значения:

```
data_woman['heduc'] = data_woman['nevermarr'].apply(lambda x : -1 if x == 1 else x)
```

Comment: столбец heduc - длительность получения образования мужем (если мужа нет стоит NaN, надо заменить на -1)
столбец newermarr - статус состоит ли человек в браке (если 1 не состоит)
нужно чтобы у всех вне брачных, срок получения образования мужем = -1.

вот попытка решения, не могу понять как в else оставить уже имеющиеся значение 
data_woman['heduc'] = data_woman['nevermarr'].apply(lambda x : -1 if x == 1 else x)

Comment: вы можете привести в вопросе пример данных на входе (2-3 строки) и то что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
   heduc  nevermarr
0    5.0          1
1    NaN          1
2    3.0          0
3    NaN          0

In [36]: df.loc[df['nevermarr']==1, 'heduc'] = df.loc[df['nevermarr']==1, 'heduc'].fillna(-1)

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   heduc  nevermarr
0    5.0          1
1   -1.0          1
2    3.0          0
3    NaN          0
```